# Why doesn't my Google Sheets word count custom function work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following function

```
function wordCount(input) {
  const count = {};
  input
      .forEach(r => {
          const words = r.split(" ")
          
          words.forEach(w => {
              w = w.replace(/[^a-zöüßä ]/i,"")
              w = w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1).toLocaleLowerCase();
              count[w] = (count[w] || 0) + 1
          })
      })

  const res = []

  for(const [word,frequency] of Object.entries(count)) {
      res.push([word,frequency])
  }

  return res;

}
```

I want to pass a column of sentences to the function, and it should return a row with two cells.

One with a unique word and the next with it's frequency in the sentences.

When using this function iv'e made I just get `r.split` is not a function. Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: could be done with formula if you are interested...

Comment: I think the solution with using inbuilt functions looks a bit messy.

Comment: up to you... but I will leave it in case you wanna try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), or if you get the values by reading a spreadsheet range and applying `.getValues()`, `input` will be a 2D array even if the range is just a single column.

Use this pattern:

```
          const words = r.map(sentence => sentence.split(" ")).flat();
```

To ensure that the custom function works when given just a single value, use this:

```
  if (!Array.isArray(input)) {
    input = [[input]];
  }
```

Alternatively, use a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula with `query()`, `regexreplace()` and `split()`. You can group by words and aggregate by counts.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(PROPER(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A&"", 
 "(?i)[^a-z öüßä 0-9]", ), " ")))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]